# React : How to handle Select condition

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.

I need to do a function where when user select "C", then all the selected options will be C.

[image]

But the problems here is that when I select "A" all the value will change to "A" also and same goes for "B". I want to make it changes for "C" only.

This is part of my code

```
handleChange = (value: any) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedAnswer: value,
  });
};

<label>Select First</label>
<Select 
  defaultValue={this.state.selectedAnswer} 
  value={this.state.selectedAnswer === "c" ? "c": this.state.selectedAnswer}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
   <Option value="a">A</Option>
   <Option value="b">B</Option>
   <Option value="c">C</Option>
</Select>

<label>Select Second</label>
<Select 
  defaultValue={this.state.selectedAnswer} 
  value={this.state.selectedAnswer === "c" ? "c": this.state.selectedAnswer}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
   <Option value="a">A</Option>
   <Option value="b">B</Option>
   <Option value="c">C</Option>
</Select>

<label>Select Third</label>
 <Select 
      defaultValue={this.state.selectedAnswer} 
      value={this.state.selectedAnswer === "c" ? "c": this.state.selectedAnswer}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
   <Option value="a">A</Option>
   <Option value="b">B</Option>
   <Option value="c">C</Option>
</Select>
```

Really appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

you are using this.state.selectedAnswer for all dropdown, so it will change the all dropdown value. Try using another variable like below.

```js
handleChange = (value: any) => {
   this.setState({
    selectedAnswer: value,
    selC:value === 'c' ? 'c' : '' //if c is not selected then reset the dropdown(in my exapmle it would be select)
    
  });
};

<label>Select First</label>
<select 
  defaultValue={this.state.selectedAnswer} 
  value={this.state.selectedAnswer === "c" ? "c": this.state.selectedAnswer}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<label>Select Second</label>

<select 
  value={this.state.selC}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
  <option>Select</option>
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<label>Select Third</label>
 <select 
     
      value={this.state.selC}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
      <option>Select</option>
   <option value="a">A</option>
   <option value="b">B</option>
   <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```